# How to implement "inverse" ioctl so the driver notify the callback to the called user application?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-kernel

In my case I am in a situation that I need the kernel driver to notify the user application about every process creation and termination (That I can archive through PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine() but it only notifies to the driver alone)
but,I need to notify this to my application with the details of the process so that the application can (take a decision that the process is to be allowed to start or not based on certain criteria) and reply to the driver so that the driver performs the action before the process is created.

Answer (score 0):

The usual means would be I/O completion ports and having the IOCTL complete asynchronously. Windows sockets have several ioctl that behave in a similar manner (notifications about available interfaces changing for example). Your client would open the driver in overlapped mode, associate the returned handle with an IOCP and provide a OVERLAPPED instance to associate the request with whatever data your program needs. The driver would save the IRP for the IOCTL in an internal queue and return STATUS_PENDING. When the event occurs the IRP is dequeued and completed.